# Importing scrapy.conf.settings generates error

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Using scrapy version 0.16. Trying to create a standalone spider runnable from a script as per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/484009). Importing the above generates this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./spiderctl.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scrapy.conf import settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scrapy/conf.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrapy.project import crawler
ImportError: cannot import name crawler
```

The file conf.py contains the line:

```
from scrapy.project import crawler
```

But the file scrapy.project is only a comment that the module is deprecated and users should instead implement the from_crawler class method. How do I implement this in the context of the code above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you an older version of `scrapy` lying around, as the most recent version doesn't have the line you mention:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/conf.py

UPDATE:

Well, it was there: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/e8e5a62c20b3d217cc55038f30e495ca183bbba7#L1R0

Try to install the most recent version and see if it works:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have v0.16 installed which is the latest stable release. I didn't install the development version though so I don't know if this is resolved. I spent more time googling this than I would have liked and finally gave up. I wanted a set of spiders able to run asynchronously from script without any magic taking place for this to happen. lxml, grequests and gevent did the job, probably in the same time it would have taken me to dig out a solution from the scrapy sources.

Comment: I also do find that scrapy has a bit of learning curve due to the googling around factor, I sometimes feel that scrapy framework is a bit of an overhead , you shouldn't need to elaborately create an entire python project generated (another bad practice) using a framework just to scrape a site.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to this question in [this new FAQ](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-m-getting-an-error-cannot-import-name-crawler):

Basically, you need to access the crawler differently, using the `from_crawler` class method instead of importing `crawler` from `scrapy.project`.

Comment: It's probably link rot, but that FAQ no longer has the required information. Ideally you should include any needed information directly in the answer, such as a sample of the new invocation method.